# django - assigning unique ids to divs in django crispy formset

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a [Django-crispy-form](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org) that is rendered as a Django [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). The form's [Layout](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html) has a `Div` element that I'd like to manipulate in Javascript. However, I don't see how to generate unique IDs for those divs. When I set `css_id`, it doesn't append an index indicating which form in the formset it belongs to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can directly assign {{ css_id }}